# Accessing NexusDB from Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, odbc, nexusdb

I am trying to get info from an embedded db called NexusDB using java.

### Alternative 1:

I've read in [NexusDB website](http://www.nexusdb.com/support/index.php?q=node/10046) that there is an ODBC driver so I might use it with unixODBC. Then I need to do a JDBC-ODBC Bridge as stated [here](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/interfaces/odbc/linux.html#jdbc_odbc).

### Alternative 2:

Get some sort of application to migrate NexusDB db to another db.
Would like to know one.

I would like to know if anyone ever this this, what's the best solution?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Alternative 1:

Not possible.

unixODBC needs linux drivers and there aren't for nexusDB.

### Alternative 2:

Didn't find any.

### Solution so far

Writting a small webservice with delphi or get odbc and use that in a small proxy.
In other words, instead of connecting to the nexusdb server you connect to a dedicated application or webservice pass on the information and that app does connect to nexusd and writes the data.

Comment: Do you need to use this db outside of java? You might consider moving to a non-embedded db engine which has proper jdbc support.

Comment: Information I need to query comes from an output of an application which is a zipFile containing nexusdb embbeded db. I can't move to a non-embedded db. All the same, nexusdb isn't only embedded, it's just this particular case.

Comment: Did you ever create this webservice and is it open source or something you can share? I would like to connect to a proprietary system that has no API and uses NexusDB, and this sounds like it would fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some success running nexusDB under wine.

I was able to set up a WINEPREFIX, follow the instructions [here](http://wiki.winehq.org/NativeOdbc) to get at wine's odbc management panel (by default it pipes into unixODBC, and as Macarse noted, that's a dead end), set up a DSN there and test that it could access the data.

The next thing I tried was installing win32 PHP and writing a quick and dirty test using odbc_connect. After wasting a good chunk of time accidently using the linux php binary and wondering why it couldn't use the (inbuilt on win32 ONLY) function odbc_connect, I did get it working.

HINT: To save yourself feeling like banging your head against a brick wall, remember that any attempts to run php scripts in this environment MUST look like this

`WINEPREFIX=/home/you/yourprefix wine php c:\phptest.php`

NOT

`WINEPREFIX=/home/you/yourprefix php c:\phptest.php`

The second version will use the linux php binary. Feeling pretty stupid after running the second version a good dozen times AND googling the error some before realising what was wrong - I think I need to get up later if I want to be able to still make things work at 4am :(

(the c:\ path in the above examples can be passed as `/home/you/yourprefix/drive_c/whatever` if you prefer - relative paths are also fine)

And yes, I know this is a necro post, but it's a pretty niche situation, there isn't a lot of information out there making nexusdb and odbc play nice on linux, and if this information was available to me a few months back when I was googling around and came across this thread it could have saved me a good chunk of time. Hope someone else finds it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect to Nexus via .NET maybe you can use [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) to run your Java app and connect through the .NET api?

Otherwise I think your own "solution so far" sounds ok.

Best
Anders

Answer (score 0):

Since it is embedded (and you probably have full access to the machine), what about copying database files to a Windows system, setting up NexusDB and its ODBC driver, then using an ODBC-JDBC bridge on that machine?  Once the bridge is running, you can set up a new JDBC-compatible DBMS of your choice, connect, and use a little code to SELECT from NexusDB and insert to your new database.

If you're looking to migrate to another embedded DBMS, I'm using [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html) for Java, and I've got to say it's really sweet.  Both embedded and client/server modes, cross-platform, and really fast for anything under 1M rows.  Supports pretty much any feature you'd have in an embedded DBMS and then some.